# Blazor 8 Web App goes in infinite loop after Azure AD redirection and cannot sign-in

Tags: azure-active-directory, blazor, openid-connect

I am using Blazor 8 WebApp with Azure AD OIDC authentication. Everything works locally but on the server, after the authentication, I can see the redirection happening infinitely until the cookie size gets too long and then it says "We can't sign you in. Please retry".

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(
    OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    options =>
     {
       var clientId = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:ClientId");
       options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
       options.SaveTokens = true;
       options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
       options.Scope.Add($"api://{clientId}/access_as_user");
       options.ClientId = clientId;
     }
```

I can see the redirection url to be the correct one with https.

Any ideas as to why the cookie once set, is not being picked up as I suspect that could be the problem.

I have tried using the ForwardedHeaders middleware.

```
var forwardedHeaderOptions = new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
  ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
};
forwardedHeaderOptions.KnownProxies.Clear();
forwardedHeaderOptions.KnownNetworks.Clear();
app.UseForwardedHeaders(forwardedHeaderOptions);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out, that I was using the incorrect certificate store path to look for the certificate. Fixed that and lo and behold!